# Play Framework: Arrow ("->") in routing

Tags: java, playframework

The [Play + Java + CRUD Activator](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play2-crud-activator#code/conf/routes) has the following `route` file, and I don't understand what `->` does in it.

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
# Home page
GET     /               controllers.Application.index()
# CRUD Controllers and REST API
->     /                play.crud.Routes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the Play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects#Splitting-the-route-file) for this is poor.  I will explain based on a nice [sample](https://github.com/josh-padnick/play-multiproject-template) on Github.

In `conf/routes` you may have:

```
->         /admin                admin.Routes
->         /customer             customer.Routes
->         /common               common.Routes
```

then, for example, `admin.Routes`, you can resolve as follows:

Look for the definition for `admin` which is in `Build.sbt`:

```
// Admin Portal
lazy val admin = project.in(file("modules/admin"))
  .dependsOn(common)
```

You see that it's in `modules/admin`. Head over to `modules/admin/conf/routes` where you'll see more routes:

```
GET        /index               controllers.admin.Application.getIndex()
```

So, Play puts that together with the original path `/admin` becoming `/admin/index`.  That is, if you bring up `/admin/index` in the browser, `controllers.admin.Application.getIndex()` will be used to serve this route.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` arrow imports routes defined in the external package `play.crud.Routes`.